# Por que se separa "ss" e "rr" na divisão silábica?

Tags: ortografia, separação-silábica

Ao dividir silabicamente, por que separa-se "ss" e "rr"? Se juntas formam um mesmo fonema, não faria mais sentido deixá-las juntas?

Exemplos:

> fer-ro
>   pro-fes-sor

Comment: Não achei uma resposta pra isso, dizem que são digrafos que não pertencem a mesma silaba, mas nunca explica o motivo...

Comment: Segundo minha antiga professora era por que estas letras brigavam... kkkk =P

Comment: @MateusDemboski também aprendi assim!! Hahaha... Será que tivemos a mesma professora ou essa é a única explicação que há? :P

Comment: Se pretender saber como se dividem as palavras na mudança de linha nos documentos oficiais da União Europeia pode ver [aqui](http://publications.europa.eu/code/pt/pt-4100200pt.htm). Quanto à razão é sobretudo uma convenção, fundada na soletração, mas que se desvia dela em casos pontuais como este.

Comment: Uma professora me explica que em latim a duplicação de uma consoante significa que a consoante termina uma sílaba e também inicia a próxima. Ao pesquisar no [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) e no Google, parece falsa esta ideia. E claramente não se aplica a português. Mas talvez esta ideia pode ser um motivo para esta divisão silábica? Ou pode ser feito assim simplesmente para parecer mais bonito na página.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-rr-` is pronounced like a first letter `r-`.
`-ss-` is pronounced like a first letter `s-` (and like a final `-s` in some dialects, esp. Brazilian Portuguese from the South of Brazil).

So

```
..........ar-
ro...........
..........as-
su...........
.............
```

is pretty readable and helps you "bridge the gap". Many other languages use the same trick: English (*drop-ping*), French (*pour-ra*), German (*ren-nen*). As far as I can tell, the hyphenation here occurs within a single phoneme, too. (Spanish (*ca-rro*) could also hyphenate `rr` as `r-r`, but that wouldn't work for `ll`, like *ca-lle*. In Spanish all other double letters only occur across morpheme boundaries.)

**I think the main reason would be readability/continuity from one line to the next.**

---

`-rr-` é pronounciado como a primeira letra `r-`.
`-ss-` é pronounciado como a primeira letra `s-` (e como a última letra `-s` no português brasileiro do sul do Brasil).

Então

```
..........ar-
ro...........
..........as-
su...........
.............
```

é bem legível e ajuda em eliminar "o fosso". Outras línguas também usam o mesmo truque: inglês (*drop-ping*), francês (*pour-ra*), alemão (*ren-nen*). Nestes exemplos, o hífen é usado no meio do fonema também. (Em espanhol (*ca-rro*) também teria a possibilidade de inserir o hífen como `r-r`, mas não no caso de `ll` (*ca-lle*). Em espanhol outras consoantes duplas só ocorrem através de morfemas.)

**Então eu acho que o motivo principal seria a legibilidade e a continuidade de uma para a próxima linha.**

Comment: Coloquei uma tradução tentativa e agradeço sempre edições quaisquer (também sem comentário). Obrigado!

Comment: Makes sense, although it's not always the case that `ss` and word-final `s` are pronounced the same.

Comment: @DanGetz You’re quite right that those are not always the same. In Portugal word-final (and indeed syllable-final) *‑s* is subject to both mandatory palatalization (always) and usually also to voicing through regressive assimilation if the next sound is voiced, whereas *‑ss‑* (and of course also *ç*) never is subject to either of those phonologic effects.  There are simple minimal pairs for this, like *podes* versus *pode-se*: in Portugal those differ only in that the first version is palatalized but the second one is not, since it is perceived as word-initial (well, clitic-initial).

Comment: @tchrist But then s- at the end of a line would never be confused to be _word_ final. (But of course, some dialects don't require that for palatalization. I think in Rio _bisnetos_ would be [biʃnɛtuʃ].)

Comment: True. In Lisbon the first *s* of *bisnetos* is certainly [ʒ], since *n* is voiced. The second one may be [ʒ] or it may be [ʃ]; it depends what comes next. All this  [ʒ] all over the place is part of why most and perhaps all dialects of European Portuguese often sound “Slavic” to non-Portuguese speakers who’ve never heard those dialects before.

Comment: É uma hipótese interessante de se pensar, mas mesmo assim me parece confuso. Por exemplo, em palavras com hífen como “super-reativo” vemos que o hífen é necessário para não ficar “superreativo” (supe-rreativo). E mesmo que o SS soe como o S de começo de palavra, quando “casa” é separada no final da linha, fica “ca-sa”.

Comment: Em castelhano, não é possível separar RR entre linhas a não ser que se trate de um prefijo que termina em *-r* e uma palavara principal que começa com *-r*.  *carro* há-de ser *ca-rro*, mas *hiperrealismo* há-de ser *hiper-realismo*

Answer (score 4):

Um livro meu dizia que era apenas por “simetria” (??!).

Mesmo com as tentativas de explicação, no fim parece uma arbitrariedade em analogia com o que outras línguas fazem, mas para o português a utilidade é pouca. Em outras línguas (francês¹, inglês²...) a presença de uma consoante dupla modifica o som da vogal anterior (encurtando ou abrindo a vogal, por exemplo), então faz sentido na escrita evitar deixar a vogal no fim da sílaba. O português deve ter copiado isso enquanto o espanhol “corrigiu” e deixa o -rr no começo da outra linha.

(¹) **le** (aprox. lâ) × **les** (lê), **appeler** (aplê) × **appelle** (apél)

(²) **be** (bi) × **bet** (bét), **write** (ráit) × **written** (ríten)

(eu ia escrever como comentário, mas como ficou grande...)

Comment: Inglês tem mais exceções que regras, ou digamos inúmeras regras, se assim quisermos mapear e explicar todos os casos. Provavelmente há regras, vamos chamar de casos, que não se encaixam nesse argumento da separação silábica (há flap T quando seria D, D quando seria T, e toda a variedade possível na pronúncia americana, só no caso do T. Se formos contar a pronúncia Britânica, as "regas" de pronúncia são outras)

Comment: Inglês é confuso mesmo. Talvez um exemplo com outra língua germânica, que usasse a mesma ideia de consoantes duplas (mas sem tantas irregularidades) fosse melhor, mas daí eu não saberia dar um bom exemplo para ilustrar... Além do mais, nunca entendi a separação silábica em inglês, parece desafiar qualquer lógica que eu possa imaginar.

Comment: É porque no inglês tudo é exceção, sobretudo quando se trata de pronúncia (um pouco de exagero mas é quase isso).